# Mocking callback or nested function in jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs, mocking

I have code as,

```
public async waitForElementSelected(element: WebdriverIO.Element) {
    /**
     * Maximum number of milliseconds to wait for
     * @type {Int}
     */
    const ms = 10000;
    await browser.waitUntil(async () =>{
      return element.isSelected();
    },{
      timeout: ms,
      timeoutMsg: 'Condition not met: Element is not selected',
      interval: 100
    });
  }
```

Here, I have easily tested wait until by mocking the browser, but I am not able to mock "isSelected" or element.isSelected(); line.

I have tried, mocking

```
global.element = {
      isSelected: jest.fn()
    };
```

But it is not working as expected, and giving element.isSelected() line still under not covered.

Following is my Test case,

```
    describe('waitForElementToBeSelected', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    mockElement = {
      isSelected: jest.fn()
    };
    mockElement.isSelected.mockReturnValue(true);

    /** **browser mock section ***/
    // global.browser = {
    //   waitUntil: ()=> {
    //     mockElement.isSelected();
    //   }
    // };
  });

  it('should call waitForElementSelected on the browser object', async () => {
    await waitActions.waitForElementToBeSelected(mockElement);
    expect(mockElement.isSelected).toHaveBeenCalled();
    // 
//expect(global.browser.waitUntil).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

This code is giving me the error, "browser not defined".
If I enabled the code,/** **browser mock section ***/
then, I am getting that, line

```
return element.isSelected()
```

is still not getting covered.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `element` is not a global variable, but an argument that you are passing into the `waitForElementSelected` function. What you need to do instead is pass an object with mock functions when calling it.

So in your test you can have it as follows:

```
// mock out the element
const mockElement = {
  isSelected: jest.fn()
};

// mock out the promise response
mockElement.isSelected.mockReturnValue(new Promise((resolve) => resolve(true)));

// call the function
waitForElementSelected(mockElement);

// expect
expect(mockElement.isSelected).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: Thanks @Ovidijus for the reply, I tried the solution but again its not giving the expected result. I tried my solution by mocking browser and waitUntill sol but still did not get expected result.

Comment: I think I know what the problem is, because you have ```async``` in ```async () => { return element.isSelected(); }```, you need to return an actual promise that will resolve itself. So you can change ```mockElement.isSelected.mockReturnValue(true);``` to ```mockElement.isSelected.mockReturnValue(new Promise((resolve) => resolve(true)));```. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @Ovidijus, But this is producing the error,

    ReferenceError: browser is not defined

      101 |   public async waitForElementToBeSelected(element: WebdriverIO.Element) {
      102 |     const ms = 10000;
    > 103 |     await browser.waitUntil(async () =>{
          |     ^
      104 |       return element.isSelected();
      105 |     },{
      106 |       timeout: ms,

Comment: Hmm, the ```global.browser = {``` appears to be mocking out the actual ```browser``` implementation inside the code you are testing. Hence the callback that you pass in never gets called. Can you change the current ```browser``` mock setup to the following: ```global.browser = { waitUntil: async (callback: () => void) => { callback(); } };```